# How to set the diffuse map in Scene Kit scene editor

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

In Ray Wenderlich's book about 3D game development using Scene Kit, the author sets the diffuse map of an object using the game scene editor in the Materials section under Properties. He instructs the reader to set this using a drop down, but I only get options that change the diffuse color and can't find how to add a map. I tried finding this option in Xcode and googling, but had no success.

How to enable this option in the editor itself? (I know I can set it with code.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by finding the image in the Media Library and then dragging and dropping the image into the property.